# Type issue in build with sharp in Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, sharp

In the image below, I can't `yarn build` the app.

I'm using **[Plaiceholder](https://plaiceholder.co/)** that depends on **[Sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/)**.

Everything is working fine, but when I build the app it crashes.

**Versions that I'm using:**

1. "react": "17.0.2"
2. "next": "12.1",
3. "sharp": "^0.31.0",
4. "@types/sharp": "^0.31.0",

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely on a TypeScript version that does not support the `type` modifier on named imports, which has been introduced in [TypeScript 4.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-modifiers-on-import-names).

Make sure you're at least on TypeScript v4.5.

```js
yarn add typescript@4.5.5
```

Or better yet, try to update to the latest TypeScript version if you can.

```js
yarn add typescript@latest
```